# Does every closed symmetric monoidal category admit a faithful monoidal functor to Sets?

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, monoidal-categories

Is there an example of a closed symmetric monoidal category which does not admit a faithful, monoidal functor to $\mathrm{Sets}$? (Here $\mathrm{Sets}$ has the usual cartesian closed structure.)

The only examples of closed symmetric monoidal categories I know of are all "concrete", i.e. admitting a faithful monoidal functor to Sets.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think the homotopy category is cartesian closed, and is not concrete (not even as a monoidal category, just as a plain category).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only examples of closed symmetric monoidal categories I know of are all "concrete", i.e. admitting a faithful monoidal functor to Sets.

I bet this is not true; probably you know that $\text{Vect}$ is a closed symmetric monoidal category, but I bet you don't know a faithful monoidal functor from $\text{Vect}$ to $\text{Set}$, because there isn't one.

To be monoidal, any such functor would have to send the $1$-dimensional vector space $k$ to the $1$-element set $1$, but since $k$ has non-identity endomorphisms but $1$ doesn't, this already prevents the functor from being faithful.

Comment: My mistake, I incorrectly used the term “faithful monoidal functor” when I actually had something else in mind. I’ll ask a separate question about this.